# Sum of the first $n$ numbers that is neither divisible by 2 nor 3.

Tags: summation, induction

Show that the sum of the first $n$ positive integers that are divisible by neither 2 nor 3 is $\frac{3}{2}n^2-\frac{1}{2}$ if $n$ is odd and is $\frac{3}{2}n^2$ if $n$ is even.

I have verified that the formulas work for the first 10 integers in the series, however, I do not know how to prove that it is true for all such positive integers. I have never dealt with a summation by cases before.

Comment: But you have tagged the question as induction. So you must be familiar with that. Have you thought about how to use induction?

Comment: Another thing to think about. What is the sum of the first $n$ positive integers (including any divisible by 2 or 3 or both)? What is the difference between that and what you are trying to prove? Does that give you any ideas?

Comment: @almagest Would I have to do induction by cases? One for when $n$ is odd and one for when $n$ is even?

Comment: Hard to predict, but pondering that will not advance matters. See what happens if you try to do a single induction on $n$. Or, if you prefer, see what happens if you try to do an induction for $n$ even. Anyway someone has now provided more hints, which are based on the idea of considering them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Let $X_n$ be the sequence of positive integers that are not divisible by 2 or 3 ordered ascending.

Your base case for odd $n$ should be where $n$ is one. Ex -- $\frac{3}{2} * 1^2 - \frac{1}{2} = 1$.

Then you need to show that if this holds for $n$, then it holds for $n+2$.

Your base case for even $n$ should be the case where $n$ is two.

Then you need to show that if this holds for $n$, then it holds for $n+2$ as well.

Comment: I think I did it! That's the route I was starting to go, I just wanted to make sure that I was going in the right direction.

Comment: @Michelle Well done! You are allowed to put up an answer yourself. Why not do that? And remember to accept one of these two answers ...

Answer (score 1):

Another idea: If you don't need to do this directly by induction, then you could try the following method.

If a number is not divisible by 2 or by 3, then it is of the form $6k + 1$ or of the form $6k + 5$ (which, of course, you should check). So let's focus on the case where $n$ is even, say $n = 2m$.

Then the first $2m$ numbers are exactly
$$
1, 5, 7, \ldots, 6m + 1, 6m + 5
$$
which we can split into two sums: 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m (6k + 1) + \sum_{k=0}^m (6k + 5)
$$
However, each of these can be evaluated by hand, just by knowing the identities
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n 1 = n+1
$$
although you should check both of these. Moreover, the usual proof of the first is by induction anyhow...